# Fetching Google Sheet data from locally mounted drive via gspread

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory, gspread, google-drive-shared-drive

I am working on a Google Colab notebook that requires the user to mount google drive using the `colab.drive` python library. They then input relative paths on the local directory tree (`/content/drive/...` by default on that mount) to files of interest for analysis. Now, I want to use a Google Sheet they can create as a configuration file. There is lots of info on how to authenticate `gspread` and fetch a sheet *from its HTTPS url*, but I can't find any info on how to access the `.gsheet` file using `gspread` that is **already mounted on the local filesystem** of the colab runtime.

There are many tutorials using this flow: https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=yjrZQUrt6kKj , but I don't want to make the user authenticate twice (having already done so for the initial mount), and i don't want to make them input some files as relative path, some as HTTPS URL.

I had thought this would be quite like using `gspread` to work with google sheets that I might have on my locally mounted drive as well. But, I haven't seen this workflow anywhere either. Any pointers in that direction might help me out as well.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please share the example code that you can tried and which is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding `.gsheet` on colab's drive you can try storing it in the user's drive and later fetch from there when needed. So until that kernel is running you won't have to re-authenticate the user.

I'm also not finding anything to authenticate into colab from other device. So you would consider modifying your flow a bit.